# Getting development build of React to communicate with backend with NGINX

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have an application that uses React for frontend and Perl for the backend.

The previous developer created an NGINX config file that handles the communication between the **built version** of the React code and the backend with no issues.

However, since NGINX is configured to work with the built version, I have to do `npm run build` every time I want to see the changes I made on the frontend side and interact with the backend.

I was wondering if it is possible to configure the NGINX file so that I can just use `npm start` to see my changes. Can this issue be resolved by making modifications to the NGINX config file or is the NGINX config file irrelevant for the development build and I just need to modify the backend code to get it working with `npm start`?

I am unfamiliar with both Perl and NGINX services. So, I am not sure which part I need to focus on. Furthermore, I had some trouble communicating with the backend on development build (`npm start`) with no NGINX config file.

Comment: Maybe just changing the URL in all your `fetch` requests to the exact ip/port your nginx server  is on running might solve your problem, and then before running `npm build` you can change them back to whatever they were. What I am saying is that, your development server is running on `localhost:3000` and your nginx server may be on some other address like `localhost:80` and maybe your fetch requests are pointing to URLs like `/api/...`. So, change them to something like `localhost:80/api/...` and before building just change them back to whatever they were.

Comment: @Jalaj Thanks for your response. Like you mentioned I had to add the server address before the URLs in order to fetch the data. I found that instead of changing all the URLs back and forth, I can just create a proxy inside package.json and toggle it on or off based on the development environment.